# V8 string compare optimization

Tags: javascript, assembly, webkit, v8, chromium

In v8 engine , in file runtime.js
exist function COMPARE

```
// ECMA-262, section 11.8.5, page 53. The 'ncr' parameter is used as
// the result when either (or both) the operands are NaN.
COMPARE = function COMPARE(x, ncr) {...}
```

So if run JS like this:

```
1 == "blabla" // -> v8 call COMPARE, but if
"anystring" == "anystring" //-> did not call, but return result
```

I think it is some kind of optimization, but i cant find this peace of code

I tried to search here,in this big func [v8/src/x64/code-stubs-x64.cc](https://github.com/v8/v8-git-mirror/blob/master/src/x64/code-stubs-x64.cc#L1513)
,but I cant, maybe because I do not know much asm instructions =(

Where it happens? 
help please

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are looking for, but the invocation for the builtin starts at line 1762. This is only reached when the earlier fast checks didn't work.

Comment: Thanks! yes, but i am not sure that this function run at all
I need to comment fast string case, and call only builtin function,it is possible?

Comment: The fast string, where the string objects are internalized and equal, is handled starting from line 1538 with the exit at 1590. Not equal internalized strings are handled from line 1699.